# Why and how to avoid Maven to replace ${id} in jsp on mvn package

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, war

When I "mvn package" my webapp, all occurences of ${id} in jsp are replace by

com.domainname.projectname:project-warname:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Maven Version 3.0.5

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Initial Jsp:

```
<c:url var="myUrl" value="/view/${id}"/>
```

Jsp in war after "mvn package":

`<c:url var="myUrl" value="/view/com.domainname.projectname:project-warname:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`"/>

How can I avoid that ?

Comment: Do you really need `<filtering>true</filtering>` in the maven-war-plugin configuration? Because that is what is causing it...

Comment: If I remove that line, maven continue to replace ${project.version} key?

Comment: Ok, I added this and it works: <filtering>true</filtering>
             <includes>
        <include>**/directoryNameWithKeysToReplace/*</include>
       </includes>

Comment: @BasicCoder consider to answer you own question and accept that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<filtering>true</filtering>
<includes>
  <include>**/directoryNameWithKeysToReplace/*</include>
</includes>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use exclude directive:

```
      <resource>
        <directory>src/my-dir</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.jsp</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are correct, but I was missing an important thing - that `<filtering>false</filtering>` does not imply that `<include>` and `<exclude>` rules are not honored - it's a different feature that "only" processes each file and does the replacements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue with js dojo files. I tried all these answers and more from [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html). The only solution that worked for me was telling it explicitly to not filter ANY js files. Like so:

```
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <!-- default value contains jpg,jpeg,gif,bmp,png -->
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>js</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
```

This should work with any file type as long as you don't need any of that file type filtered.